# Small-string optimization - how to efficiently keep track of string mode

Tags: c++, arrays, string, algorithm, optimization

I have been trying to understand how the small-string optimization works for std::string and have been reading this:

https://joellaity.com/2020/01/31/string.html

I have an issue with finding the right way to set the flag that determines the mode of the string (short mode = using just the limited array on the stack, long mode = when the fixed array is no longer enough, a dynamic one is allocated)
Below I listed some of the things I understood from the article and a video by a Facebook developer and my issues with getting the right method:

From what I understand:

1. Great effort is taken to not have to add extra data to the string, so the flag that determines if it's a small string or not is set somewhere internally
2. The character array does not start in the same byte index in both modes, as in short-string mode the first byte is used to count (alternatively the last byte can be used to count down and becomes a null terminator when hitting 0 in this variation https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kPR8h4-qZdk)
3. However, using a counter at the end of the string would interfere if you want to use the last bit of the last byte as a flag to determine the string mode - assuming the last byte in the short mode will always be null-terminated, setting the least significant bit to 1 would indicate that it's in long-string mode (and of course when you read the capacity you will have to return a value with a cleared LSB every time, and should guarantee the capacity is always an even number, so that having a LSB set to 1 is always a flag and never part of the true value of capacity)
4. So we end up with a case where we either need to make sure there is extra data allocated for the string (as they explain in the video), so we can put some bookkeeping beyond the last character and null terminator, or we put the string mode flag at the end and a counter for short-mode at the start, which would mean that every time you need the character buffer, you have to check if it's short mode, to return from index 1 instead of the true start of the array
5. Furthermore, it is not quite clear how the Facebook string checks for the mode in case it's in short-string mode, as then it will not have an allocation with extra space for bookkeeping

It seems that it's unavoidable to check which string mode is currently set on each and every string operation and each time you want to access the size or capacity, however in the Facebook implementation in the video they at least have the character buffer start at the first byte of the object, for both small and large mode.
The issue is it was not entirely clear how to check for the string mode. The check they mentioned relies on dynamic allocation and extra bytes at the end, but to even access them you have to first know if it's a string in long mode (dynamically allocated), so it becomes circular.
They mention that you can use a few bytes from the counter at the end in short-string mode to check for the mode, however once again this would require you to know it's short-string mode in advance, otherwise in long-mode it could just be any value since the capacity can be any value.

Assuming the layout is this (in 64-bit, so we assume each field is 8 bytes and the total size is 24):

```
struct StringLayout
{
    union
    {
        struct
        {
             char* Arr;
             size_t Count;
             size_t Capacity;
        }Data;
        char Raw[24];
    };
};
```

In short-string mode:

1. The last byte is used for a countdown for the remaining free spaces and once it reaches 0 it becomes a terminator
2. The rest of the bytes are free to use for characters
3. All the bytes between the last set byte and the 24th one are null terminated as well
4. The LSB of the last byte that is used as a counter can both be 1 and 0 for different values, so it can't be relied upon as a flag

In long-string mode:

1. It works as we'd expect, with Arr pointing to a dynamic array with a certain Capacity while Count is the number of characters set and after the last character there is a null-terminator
2. The LSB of the last byte (that belongs to Capacity) can also be either 1 or 0, and even if we limit Capacity to be only even numbers, it doesn't help because in short mode the counter can also be even numbers or even 0.

Is there any way to set a flag somewhere in these 24 bytes that can be reliably checked for the string mode, as well as to not have to move the first index one step ahead in short-mode? (as they are describing in the joellaity article)

Comment: No matter how long the string is, its size must be known, somehow. There's your "mode": if size < N bytes, it's SSO, if it's N bytes or greater, it's a real string.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik yes, but isn't the size checked differently (for short mode you only use one byte at start or end to save space)

Comment: @ulakblade `std::string` has to track its size (and capacity) no matter what, so why do you think checking the size would differ based on the mode?

Comment: @RemyLebeau because in short mode, they are trying to maximize the amounts of bytes saved and also leveraging the fact that since it's a small array, its size can be counted by a small number of bits (hence using the first or last byte)

Comment: Looks like the special sauce is a bunch of UB that I'll assume the devs have tested the smurf out of and proven behaves as expected on all target platforms: `bool __is_long() const _NOEXCEPT {return bool(__r_.first().__s.__size_ & __short_mask);}` Whether the string is long or not, it looks at it as a short string, and tests the size to see if the least significant bit is set or not. This is the sort of stuff you can get away with in a library implementation where you know the compiler, the target platforms and are extremely intimate with both. Basically, don't try this at home, kiddies.

Comment: @user4581301 so in this case, each time you want to get the character array, you must perform this check and then if it's in small mode, return the array from index 1, otherwise return from index 0 normally via the "long" part of the union?

I wonder how much the small string optimization actually compensates for this huge increase in operations since this will be done on every method that tries to access any field of the string

Comment: It's always a trade off. the basic GCC implementation said, "Screw it. 40 bytes. and full speed ahead!" Which is more important? That said, testing one bit should be pretty cheap.

Comment: You're poking around in the _implementation_ of a standard library class, therefore it would be useful to say in the body of your question which implementation you're examining.  e.g. which compiler and which architecture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple options:

1. Assuming a little-endian byte order, you will always have `capacity` greater than 2<sup>48</sup> if it's a short string, and that's too long for a heap-allocated string.  This requires a special case for 23-character strings that end in non-terminating nulls, but that's not bad.
2. For heap-allocated strings, always set the upper and lower 8 bits of `capacity` to 0xFF.  Again this gives you 48 bits to use for capacity information, which is more than enough.  This has the advantage of working in any byte order.

Comment: If you also use the upper bits of capacity, does that mean that all 8 bytes of it can not be used in the short string?
Originally I thought of only using the last byte as a counter in short-string mode, which would free up all the other bytes, I just didn't know how to also use it as a check for the mode, because the last byte of the capacity in long mode could be any value

Comment: No, you don't need to *check* both bytes.  If capacity for heap-allocated strings is always 0xFFxxxxxxxxxxxxFF, then to see if it's a short string you just need to check Raw[23].  If `Raw[23] != 0xFF` then it's a short string.  On a little-endian machine, you're checking the high byte, and on a big-endian machine, you're checking the low byte.  You don't need to know which it is.